# ThunderBird/Lighting synchronisation with SE k770i

Tags: linux, thunderbird, calendar.app

I want to synchronise (both ways) data between Google Mail and Google Calendar with my Thunderbird with Ligtning + Zindus and SE k770i mobile phone.

I have w working configuration of Ligtning and Google Calendar. Contacts between Google Mail and Thunderbird are in sync with help of Zindus addon.

Now I need a way to add my mobile to this stack.

Ideal solution would work both on Windows and Linux, but Windows only solution will suffice.

I'm using now MyPhoneExplorer on my Windows machine, it can sync with Google Calendar and Contacts, so it's partial solution (doesn't work well under Wine on Linux).

Answer (score 2):

If your mobile phone is supported, you could run [Funambol mobile client](https://www.forge.funambol.org/download/) on your phone and install the [Mozilla sync plugin](https://mozilla-plugin.forge.funambol.org/) into Thunderbird. Both sync the local calendars and contacts with a Funambol server (you can use their service or run your own).

Answer (score 0):

I'd just try and look for ways of directly syncing your phone with Google Calendar/Contacts.

Does [this](http://www.google.com/mobile/products/sync.htm) not work with your phone? Otherwise try [GooSync](http://www.goosync.com/), I've used their paid service before and found it works really well. Your phone is listed on their [Supported Devices](http://www.goosync.com/SupportedDevices.aspx) page.